# Ubuntu killed Window volume. How to reinstall window from Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-partition

**Ubuntu killed Window partition**

Hey guys, I have this trouble. At first my Lap has Ubuntu and Window. But the grub has crashed and the best way to save it was backup data and reinstall OS.

I chose to install Window7 first, after that was Ubuntu. The mistake happened and i didn't recognize was ***The volume after shrinked for Ubuntu was LOGICAL.*** And when then I let Ubuntu chose the place to live automatically so it killed my former Window ~cry~

Anyone have some info about how to gparted this Volume and re-install Window7 from Ubuntu OS ? Give me some instruction or links as possible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if that image represents your PC's true situation, then your installed Windows is pretty much gone for good. Irrecoverable. Because you reformatted that partition from ntfs to ext and did overwrite the allocated space with your Ubuntu.

Next i will present the easiest solution i could use and i do use to dual-boot Win+Ubuntu for more than 5 years now. It doesn't necessary means it's the best one, it's just the one than makes most sense to me. Other people may find other/better solutions.

First i boot a Live Ubuntu and sanitize my hard disk: in GParted i erase all partitions, all of it. Just empty space. Then i decide if a want BIOS-MBR partitioning or a UEFI-GPT one. It's actually a matter of motherboard capability, it's either BIOS or UEFI (UEFI is more modern solution).

I create a new partition table (MBR or GPT) in GParted, but i create no partition (yet). I reboot, i remove the Live Ubuntu medium and insert the Windows installation medium. I let Windows install itself the way it wants (with system, recovery and main partitions, whatever).

When Windows installation has finished, i reboot , i remove the Windows installation medium and insert the Live Ubuntu back again. I boot into Live Ubuntu again, open GParted and create one ext partition after the Windows partition. I DO NOT delete or merge any of the partitions created by Windows.

At this point i have 3 primary Windows partitions + one Ubuntu primary partition. This is possible even for older BIOS computers. Next, for BIOS-MBR PCs i create an extended partition and create a swap partition inside the extended space. UEFI-GPT supports 6 primaries easily, so no need for the extended trick.

I apply changes in GParted, then i click the install Ubuntu icon. I choose the "install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option. When asked where i want Ubuntu installed i point to the ext partition. I choose to install GRUB to /sda, meaning the root of the harddisk, not to a specific partition like /sda1, /sda2, etc.

After the installation finishes, i reboot, i remove the Live Ubuntu medium, and the GRUB menu should present itself asking me to choose what OS to start: Ubuntu or Windows. That's all! Easy-Peasy dual-booting for newbies.

Comment: I did two first step like u said. But when i search some info about GPT and MBR or msdos when create new partition table. ** I CHOSE GPT ** 

And now it appears this when I use "try to install ubuntu "

" /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.  However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.  Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table? "

Did I do it wrong something

Comment: You did nothing wrong. MBR and msdos partition table are basically the same thing. If you created the GPT using GParted, try something else: create a new GPT with (Gnome) Disks. And make sure you bootable USB is GPT too. If one drive is GPT and the other one is MBR (no matter which is what) the GRUB will not install correctly and won't be able to boot the installed Ubuntu.