# Dual Booting with linux & windows, cannot boot to windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-10

I installed Linux on a Windows machine. I make music, so I use `live 9`, which is not for Linux, `MAKE IT FOR LINUX`!

I wanted to boot to Linux, but well Linux gimp or boot select is fine, but I made it like that, when windows will boot, it's boot will automatically redirect to Linux.

So, what happens (behind the scenes):

1. Windows boot manager automatically redirects to Linux
2. Linux will give me a selection between Ubuntu, memory-test, memory-test 2 and Windows 10.
3. When I select Windows 10, it will return me to same spot (machine boots to Windows, but then again windows boot manager redirects to Linux).

So I need to boot to windows to change it to normal or to change something with files (via Linux) well, I am on my own with file change and copys from other machines boot stuff is pretty much same and with booting to Windows.

I need to get it not redirect me to Ubuntu, I think maybe an USB ISO will work, but I am not sure.

If it works I will add it to this as answer and close this topic.

I know it takes time to answer, so I posted it already.

HELP! Thanks -Ras

**BASIC RECAP:**
Cannot dual boot to Linux, because the Windows boot manager redirects to Ubuntu. I could change it when I can boot 1 time to windows (maybe an ISO will work, downloading it for USB).

Or maybe via Linux, some terminal or file manager way.

*It was my fault, I can still somehow unistall Linux (if that can work), because I haven't have time to do something yet. (My Linux delete theory works with: machine will boot to windows boot manager, it will TRY to redirect to Linux, but wait, because there is no Linux, so otherwise it will redirect to windows, where I can change files.)*

Comment: It would be best to boot into a LiveDVD/USB Ubuntu, open GParted, make a screenshot of the partition map and post it here. You probably installed GRUB on same partition as Windows bootloader. That's a confusing situation for Win bootloader, perhaps that's why it redirects you back to Ubuntu instead of booting Windows. You need to move or reinstall GRUB to the root of your harddisk, NOT to a specific partition.

Comment: Whatever you do don't uninstall simply Linux, this will leave you with even less options to fix something, we have a few good people here who have pretty good knowledge with that.

Comment: @ipselute as i mentioned: i made it do that, first i had a choice by windows to ubuntu or windows, everytime i selected ubunutu, i got the ubunutu version of that, so i told windows (while in windows, booted up) to default to ubuntu, no questions asked, but i didn't think about that windows boot will redirect to ubuntu again.

Comment: ok, i will not unistall, it was just an idea. Well 13 year brains are not the best :)

Comment: BTW, i installed linux with the guide on the link, just instead of i managing with the files on linux, i selected the install next to windows option.. [link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxepmtjmilQ

Comment: i have my iso downloaded, gonna find out, how to get it on usb and gonna boot it. All answers welcome [link] http://askubuntu.com/questions/780014/making-bootable-usb-via-make-startup-disk

Comment: Just remember that Windows bootloader is a nasty guy. It doesn't play nice with anybody but other Windows. GRUB (Ubuntu's bootloader) plays nice with everybody (even with Macs). If you want to dual-boot Win+Ubuntu you must let the GRUB "play the music", to lead the booting process, because Win bootloader is always grumpy and doesn't wanna share. Let Win bootloader install to its' dedicated partition and install GRUB "in front" of Win bootloader, meaning in the root of your hard disk. This will "defeat" the grumpy guy.

Comment: @ipselute nice story :) well that means i need to unistall windows somehow and reinstall? Oh nope, saw your other comment.. So how can i get linux to rock? (gonna try the windows iso usb booting to windows for changing windows boot stuff) So, it will stay like windows will get, that windows is the only one... Well i think the best is to get an SSD for one of them..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40916/discussion-on-question-by-rasmus-a-dual-booting-with-linux-windows-cannot-boo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, how i solved my problem:

1. I downloaded the Windows `iso` file.
2. Made one of my USB sticks Bootable (with Windows `iso`)
3. Booted up, selected language, then i pressed repair this pc
4. Then from there i booted up to windows, where i could change the windows boot manager order (from ubuntu default 0 timeout to ubuntu default, 6 sec timeout)
5. Disabled GRUB (timeout = 0) (because windows was installed first so it got the windows selection first)

This guide was accualy made by Amir, but i had my situations so some shoutouts! (i didn't use the commands, since i had a gui on booted up windows) I would mark Amir's one as accepted, because i think lots of others will find him's more useful.

- **Amir**, who made the original guide
- **ipse lute**, who helped alot with troubleshooting & understanding the problem
- **Videonauth**, who edited my original question & gave some basic answers
- **Mark Kirby**, who quickly responded to me & helped to make the question proper for askubuntu

Also, thanks for everybody, who were here to help.

Comment: Sorry for being annoying, but i just don't understand how you did that magic. Windows bootloader doesn't recognize GRUB without external help. I have a dual-boot laptop: Win8+Xubuntu 16.04. I entered Windows, press Winlogo+R, typed msconfig in it and opened 'System Configuration'. I get to the Boot tab and all i see is Windows: Current OS: Default OS. No other entries, no sign of ANY linux there. Maybe you used a third party app like Grub2Win? Or maybe you entered Grub in edit mode and changed boot order from there?

Comment: i installed EasyBCD on Windows, on that select 'Add New Entry' then Select Linux/BSD, there select GRUB 2 & name,  then 'Add Entry' then 'Edit Boot Menu'. From there i think you can undrestand :)

Comment: *you are not annoing & from GRUB i just changed timeout to 1 sec, so it is there, if any case something horrible happens :)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you can log into Ubuntu, so `grub` must be working fine. Windows won't load, so there must be something wrong with your Windows bootloader. You need to fix it to regain access to Windows.

1. Use a Windows disc or live usb drive to initiate windows start-up repair. Remember that you should use the same one that is already installed on your computer.
2. You can see there is a system restore point. If there is one, you might be able to restore it. You can look for it after you boot using Windows disc or live usb.
3. The last option is to repair your bootloader using command prompt. You will need to run some commands after booting with a windows disc or live usb. This [link](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows) has a step by step guide on using the commands. It's a bit advanced so I suggest you exercise caution and read thoroughly before trying it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 0. Thanks     1. it came with win 7, updated it to win 10 (from dell)     2.ok, but how i make my usb bootable [link] http://askubuntu.com/questions/780014/making-bootable-usb-via-make-startup-disk     3. thanks,  i will get some other pc, i can do longer stuff tommorow, since i don't have time. Hopes up :) I will be here for only 15 min!

Comment: At this point I think you should do a clean Windows installation. You can take back up of your important files from the C drive if you log into Ubuntu and access your hard drive. You can see the link I am providing to make bootable usb drive. 
http://mspoweruser.com/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-drive-for-windows-10/

Comment: Installing Windows again will overwrite the GRUB (Ubuntu's bootloader), thus rendering Ubuntu unusable. And then you will reinstall Ubuntu (and its' GRUB) again, thus rendering Windows bootloader unusable (like before) and will not be able to use Windows (again). And this is called getting into and endless loop. If you really want to dual-boot correctly, see my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/779131/ubuntu-killed-window-volume-how-to-reinstall-window-from-ubuntu/779151#779151.

Comment: @Amir well, from files i am great (google drive, all my files are in 1GB :))

Comment: @ipselute Well i will try to undrestand... Probaly i am good with both asking me... (For this pc) and for others, you should make a video so everybody can google it :)..  I will comment here later today.. I will try to get windows ask for me to go to one or another..  I will get your guide up, when i am getting a new pc, FOR EVERYONE ELSE, GET IPSE LUTE GOOD REP!