# Making bootable usb via Make Startup Disk

Tags: live-usb, startup-disk-creator

So, i need to make my usb bootable windows, i cannot select the .iso file.

(need it for [Dual Booting with linux & windows, cannot boot to windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779996/dual-booting-with-linux-windows-cannot-boot-to-windows?noredirect=1#comment1167461_779996) )

Comment: What is your ubuntu version?

Comment: 16.04 LTS COMMENT NEEDS AT LEAST SOME TEXT

Comment: Screenshots, please?

Comment: well, if i sellect an iso, it will go back to this (nothing changes) http://prntscr.com/bape1q

Comment: Making a windows usb on Ubuntu 16.04 seems like quite a problem right now, I found this http://onetransistor.blogspot.co.uk/2016/04/install-winusb-on-ubuntu-1604-lts.html but I can't get it to work.

Comment: "Let's mention again that WinUSB can't make UEFI bootable drives!" Windows 10 is UEFI :(

Comment: Startup Disk Creator will only make Ubuntu (and Ubuntu-based) bootable USB's. Did you have any luck using Unetbootin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, you just need to get on your friend's Windows PC & get your USB stick, what has previously downloaded `Rufus` & `iso`.

Shoutouts to **Mark Kirby**, who tried to answer this question and also responded quick on my last question and **pHeliOn**, who accualy answered this question.